# TextViews not shown in gridLayout - Android

Tags: android, xamarin

I have this strange problem when I add my custom views to a GridLayout. All the textviews in my Custom view are hidden (or gone, don't know) and when I click my Custom View, they appear.

This is my Custom View:

```
public class SequenceVOView : LinearLayout
{
    TextView lblTitle;
    TextView lblTheme;
    TextView lblDeadline;
    List<ImageView> stars;
    ImageView imgSequenceBadge;
    ImageView imgRightArrow;
    private QuestionSequenceVO _sequence;
    public QuestionSequenceVO Sequence {
        get {
            return this._sequence;
        }
        set {
            _sequence = value;
        }
    }
    public SequenceVOView (Context context) :
        base (context)
    {
        Initialize ();
    }
    public SequenceVOView () :
    base (Application.Context)
    {
        Initialize ();
    }

    public SequenceVOView (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) :
        base (context, attrs)
    {
        Initialize ();
    }

    public SequenceVOView (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) :
        base (context, attrs, defStyle)
    {
        Initialize ();
    }

    void Initialize ()
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)Context.GetSystemService (Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        View view = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.SequenceVOFragmentLayout, this);
        lblTitle = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.lblSequenceSubject);
        lblTheme = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.lblSequenceTheme);
        lblDeadline = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.lblDeadline);
        stars = new List<ImageView> ();
        stars.Add(FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.imgSequenceStar1));
        stars.Add(FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.imgSequenceStar2));
        stars.Add(FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.imgSequenceStar3));
        stars.Add(FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.imgSequenceStar4));
        stars.Add(FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.imgSequenceStar5));
        foreach (var item in stars) {
            item.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.difficultyStar);
            item.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
        }
        imgRightArrow = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imgSequenceRightArrow);
        imgSequenceBadge = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imgSequenceBadge);
    }
    public void setData(QuestionSequenceVO sequence){
        _sequence = sequence;
        lblTitle.Text = sequence.Subject;
        lblTheme.Text = sequence.Category;
        lblDeadline.Text = sequence.DueDate;
        for (int i = 0; i < sequence.Difficulty; i++) {
            stars [i].Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        }
        imgRightArrow.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.arrowRight);
        imgSequenceBadge.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.imgVragenreeks);
    }
}
```

the wierd part is: My images are shown correctly. Any Ideas?

**EDIT:**
apparently in gridView and gridLayout the Textviews are set to white when not selected and to black if selected. Found it when it changed my theme to default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently in gridView and gridLayout the Textviews are set to white when not selected and to black if selected. Found it when it changed my theme to default.

Answer (score 0):

The `ImageView` is showing up because you created a list with `ImageView` as the element (`stars = new List<ImageView> ();`). If you want to display both an `ImageView` and a `TextView`, I woudl suggest that you create a custom `GridView` that displays a custom grid object. An excellent tutorial on how to accomplish this may be found here: http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/01/android-custom-gridview.html

Comment: Images that are not in the list<ImageView> are showing too. Its just wierd all textViews are hidden. I'll try your example. Maybe It's better to work with the gridView instead of Grid Layout for this.

Comment: Doesn't fix the problem. It still doesn't show my textviews. only imageviews are shown.

Comment: apparently in gridView and gridLayout the Textviews are set to white when not selected and to black if selected. Found it when it changed my theme to default.

Comment: your `TextView`s are visible now?

Comment: yep, everything is ok now :)